KiCAD gives error "Input power pin not driven by any output power pins" with VBAT connected to battery symbol
I connected VBAT to a battery symbol and battery to GND, but I still get the error "Input power pin not driven by any output power pins."
What am I doing wrong?
Schematic screenshot:


You need to place a power flag on nodes where you get that error: -


I'a a bit newbie, but how to connet it with battery and with Power Output Flag? Just connect it to the wire between VBAT pin and Battery or in some other way?

You could do that, or just have all your power bus symbols connected to their own power flags off in the corner somewhere. It's just for DRC, there's no associated footprint or anything.
